# Filterset from WPF CollectionViewSource

Tags: wpf, collectionviewsource

How do you get the resultset from the CollectionViewSource once it's filtered? Actually, all I need is the count, but I assume sure the answers go together. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`collectionViewSource.View` returns the active view. Therefore once the filtering is complete the `collectionViewSource.View` would represent the items which returned true during the filter. If you wanted the entire underlying collection for whatever reason you would access that via `collectionViewSource.View.SourceCollection`.

```
int count = 0;

  IEnumerable items = collectionViewSource.View;
  foreach (var item in items)
      count++;
```

Comment: Bob, the above is assuming that you have already done a filter on the collection.  Once the filter has processed the current view (CollectionViewSource.View above) is changed to reflect those items.  Unfortunately ICollectionViewSource (Which is what is returned) does not have a count method.

Comment: @OffApps Cory I will add clarification for the OP

Comment: Thanks, Aaron! This seems obvious now.